# Using Eval() in Custom Server Control InnerProperty

Tags: asp.net, custom-server-controls

I've created a server control (not a user control... no ascx) with a string InnerProperty:

```
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
[BindableAttribute(true)]
public string LabelText {
    get { return Label.Text; }
    set { Label.Text = value; }
}
```

And when given a plain string in the markup it works fine:

```
<Custom:SpecialTextBox ID="Box" runat="server" >
    <LabelText>
        Some Text
    </LabelText>
</Custom:SpecialTextBox>
```

If I use this control in a databound control (e.g. ListView) and want to use the Eval method in that InnerProperty:

```
<Custom:SpecialTextBox ID="Box" runat="server" >
    <LabelText>
        Some <%# Eval("TextType") %> Text
    </LabelText>
</Custom:SpecialTextBox>
```

I receive a parser error:

> The 'LabelText' property of 'Custom:SpecialTextBox' does not allow
>   child objects.

Is there an attribute or something that I can put on the property to make this work? Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you assign LabelText to the eval inline, e.g. `<Custom:SpecialTextBox LabelText='<%# Eval("TextType")%>'></Custom:SpecialTextBox>`?

Comment: @DaveZych it's a bit strange: what you suggested works but if I want to combine it with static text (LabelText='Some <%# Eval("TextType")%> Text') the Eval doesn't evaluate.

Comment: What about when you only have the Eval inside the LabelText element without the Some Text words?

Comment: @DaveZych yes, as I mentioned it works with a straight Eval only but I need the person writing the markup to be able to combine other text. They could combine yours and woohoo's solution below (so it would be LabelText='<%# "Some " + Eval("TextType") + "Text" %>'  to do it but it feels a little less natural than what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you have C# code it must be enclosed in <%#...%>.
You've got to use the `Eval` inside a server-side control so add `runat="server"` attribute to `LabelText`.
Try this:

```
<Custom:SpecialTextBox ID="Box" runat="server" >
    <LabelText runat="server">
        <%# "Some " + Eval("TextType") + " Text"%>
    </LabelText>
</Custom:SpecialTextBox>
```

Comment: That produces the same error. The parser seems to be treating the <%# %> as a child object/element (I thought the asp engine might have executed the Eval first but that doesn't seem to be the case).

Comment: What is this `LabelText` element? If you want to use `Eval` you must use it inside server-side controls...

Comment: @kad81: please review my edit, and please mark the answer if it has helped you. thanks.